# How to reach a human responsible for https://community.idera.com/?

Tags: account-management, permissions, contacts

I'm a registered user of Embarcadero C++-Builder and have signed up at https://community.idera.com/ to discuss some problems I have with the IDE. Like in the following thread:

https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/general-development/f/rad-studio-general/67573/how-to-avoid-linking-problems-in-case-of-files-using-the-same-name

I was able to answer in that thread yesterday once, but all created answers afterwards vanished either with no message at all, one telling me about some general error and I should retry or in very few cases even mentioning outstanding abuse reports. Within the community site there's no hint to any abuse report and I didn't get anything by mail, so there's simply nothing I could answer to. Of course I'm not spamming at all, I was only trying to answer two times in the same thread because of newer findings related to my problem and because multiple independent answers would easily increase readability. The content of the answer was some XML and paths, not even URLs or anything.

Not being able to create additional answers with new valuable findings is one problem, the other is that the one answer that I was able to create yesterday vanished now as well, simply because I was editing it to clear up some statements. I didn't find any contact form or moderator access or such for the community forum itself, so I don't know what the actual issue is, what happened to my answers, what I need to do to be able to answer at all in future etc.

So, do you know of any method to actually talk to someone in charge for that site and describe them my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try [contact us](https://www.ideracorp.com/contactus), social media  on https://www.idera.com/ or email the authors of posts on https://community.idera.com/database-tools/blog/

Comment: Already tried various info@ and got some weird error response about Google groups, which doesn't make sense to me. I didn't see anything to post to bloggers or other community members, but have missed Facebook, so thanks for that hint.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I did write to all `info@...` and alike addresses I could find and posted on the companies Facebook page etc., I (of course?) didn't get any response from a human yet. I got some automatic mail responses for some of the `info@...` addresses about not being able to post into that Google group(?!) because I'm not allowed to.

BUT after ~4 days of silence I recently received the mentioned abuse mails from the community itself:

> A few days ago we emailed you about your post, RE: How to avoid linking problems in case of files using the same name?. That message was to let you know your post was flagged as inappropriate - so it's hidden from the site right now. However, that removal isn't permanent yet. You have until 26 Jan 2019 7:41 PM to send us an appeal using this form. Note that if you don't appeal the abusive finding, your post will be permanently deleted from the site on 26 Jan 2019 7:41 PM

Those contain a link like the following where one is expected to input some text to describe why one thinks the post ion question has been marked wrongly. Of course one doesn't get any clue about if the mark was about spam or abuse, who did mark why etc.

http://community.idera.com/abuseappeal?AbuseAppealID=[...]

In the end I simply described the whole problem again, mentioned that the mails came pretty late, that there wasn't anyone to reach, that it's pretty unclear what they want me to put into the answer to the abuse report etc. After sending all that a message states that things will get reviewed and it seems one can only wait again.

The important thing to note is that after receiving those mails after ~4 days if silence one has only few hours to answer oneself and in my case we have weekend now. So depending on how those reports are processed etc., it might be that my answer will only be seen at next business day, which would be too late in theory.

Looks to me like the whole process could be improved a bit.

Comment: Still no response from any human, but at least my answers have been restored. :-)